# Pancake coil AWG requirements for specific voltage and dimensions

Tags: transformer, planar-inductor

I am creating a project and I am not an expert in electrical engineering, but I want to design a pancake coil with the maximal inductance to operate in 230V-50Hz and with dimensions of 60mm outer diameter, 5mm inner diameter and 5mm height, I want to calculate what AWG I need for the wire in order that it can withstand the current produced in this conditions.

Comment: Maximum inductance means maximum turns around an iron core.

Comment: 60 mm diameter, 230 V applied? Very, very, very thin wire.